# Rails 4.2 is serving stylesheets twice in development mode

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

I'm started a new project:

```
rails new test-styles
cd test-styles
rails generate controller CreditCards open
rails server
```

This is the produced HML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/credit_cards-1ed56f25de9e08bdac6a0e4c565de8ec.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-5760c24f7be45363d79a66235e9d6b39.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
```

And Here the content of each css:

application.css

```
/* line 4, /.../test-styles/app/assets/stylesheets/credit_cards.scss */
body {
  background: red;
}
```

credit_card.css

```
/* line 4, /.../test-styles/app/assets/stylesheets/credit_cards.scss */
body {
  background: red;
}
```

As we can see application.css is included credit_cards so why is credit_cards also included in the page?

This is very annoying because I would like to use the gem `twitter-bootstrap-rails` and also less variables. Of course if credit_cards is compile alone, it will fail...

I'm new to RoR, maybe I messed something...

Answer (score 1):

You paste it wrong... Rails's application css has lines:

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

These lines use all css files in directory assets/stylesheets of your application. More information about it is [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: By content I mean when it's generated.

Comment: Thanks for your link. "In development mode, assets are served as separate files in the order they are specified in the manifest file." I removed the two lines you paste and use the @import directive from less. With css it's not really an issue to have the rules twice.